# Transform dataframe in order to be able to filter values

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I would like to transform the following dataframe into a new dataframe where I will be able to filter a coefficient like this:

Example:

sample %>% filter(Age == "18-30")

Result should give the coefficient for Age "18-30".

I dont want to use match method! I have tried `pivot_longer()` but it does not produce the dataframe structure that i want.

```
sample <- data.frame (GLM_Coefficient  = c(0.6, 1, 0.4, 0.2, 0, 3 ,1 ,2,1),
                  Category = c("France", "UK", "USA", "18-30", "31-50", "51-70", "70+", "100-170", "171+"),
                  Type = c("Country", "Country", "Country", "Age", "Age", "Age", "Age", "Height", "Height")
)



  GLM_Coefficient Category    Type
1             0.6   France Country
2             1.0       UK Country
3             0.4      USA Country
4             0.2    18-30     Age
5             0.0    31-50     Age
6             3.0    51-70     Age
7             1.0      70+     Age
8             2.0  100-170  Height
9             1.0     171+  Height
```

Comment: You can just filter on multiple columns, right? `filter(sample, Category == "18-30" & Type == "Age")`

Answer (score 0):

If you only wnat the coefficent, you have to filter on both `Type` and `Category` and then select `GLM_coefficient`:

```
sample %>% filter(Type == "Age", Category == "18-30") %>% select(GLM_Coefficient)
```

If you don't want it to be a tibble, you need to add `pull`:

```
sample %>% filter(Type == "Age", Category == "18-30") %>% select(GLM_Coefficient) %>% pull()
```